# Merge jquery selector [javascript string concat]

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, string-concatenation

I'm trying to make a jquery-selector generator for my two filters - the aim is just hidding some elements in a calendar -

If I filter on the group DB_ID 2 and on the personn DB_ID 1 I would like to generate the following selector : 
`#mod_calendar .gid_2.pid_1`

If I filter on the group DB_ID 2 I would like to generate the following selector : `#mod_calendar .gid_2`

If I filter on the personn DB_ID 1 I would like to generate the following selector : `#mod_calendar .pid_1`

If I filter on the group DB_ID 2,5,6,8 and on the personn DB_ID 1 I would like to generate the following selector : 
`#mod_calendar .gid_2.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_5.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_6.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_8.pid_1`

If I filter on the group DB_ID 2,5,6,8 and on the personn DB_ID 1,2 I would like to generate the following selector : 
`#mod_calendar .gid_2.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_5.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_6.pid_1,#mod_calendar .gid_8.pid_1#mod_calendar .gid_2.pid_2,#mod_calendar .gid_5.pid_2,#mod_calendar .gid_6.pid_2,#mod_calendar .gid_8.pid_2`

And so one, I think you get the point...
this https://jsfiddle.net/5mr60f6p/1 is what I tried so far but I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

**[EDIT]**

```
<div id="mod_calendar">
<div class="pid_1 gid_1">pid_1 gid_1 [do not match gid_filter should not be shown]</div>
<div class="pid_2 gid_2">pid_2 gid_2 [do not match pid_filter should not be shown]</div>
<div class="pid_5">pid_5 [do not match gid_filter should not be shown]</div>
<div class="pid_5 gid_2">pid_5 gid_2 [match gid_filter and pid_filter should be shown]</div>
</div>
```

JS code :

```
var pid_filter= [5,32,56,8,4];
var gid_filter=[2,5];
function generate_filter_selector(prefix,values){
    return prefix+values.join(','+prefix);
}
console.log($(generate_filter_selector('#mod_calendar .pid_',test)).show());
//I would like the intersection of both selector and not like I did one after the other.
console.log($(generate_filter_selector('#mod_calendar .gid_',test2)).show());
```

What I would like to obtain with this exact exemple and those two arrays is this :

```
$("#mod_calendar pid_5.gid_2,#mod_calendar pid_32.gid_2,#mod_calendar pid_56.gid_2,#mod_calendar pid_8.gid_2,#mod_calendar pid_4.gid_2,#mod_calendar pid_5.gid_5,#mod_calendar pid_32.gid_5,#mod_calendar pid_56.gid_5,#mod_calendar pid_8.gid_5,#mod_calendar pid_4.gid_5").show();
```

Like I said in the comment I would like to have the intersection of both filters.

Comment: I'v got no idea what you are asking or what the problem is. The fiddler has 1 line of code which concatenates two strings and you want us to do what? Can you make the question a little more clear and show more code and the specific problem you are having?

Comment: @Esko I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or even faster :

```
function generate_jquery_selector_from_fitlers(filters,prefix,item_prefix){
        prefix = prefix || '';
        item_prefix = item_prefix || '.';
        return prefix+item_prefix+allPossibleCases(filters).join(' ,'+prefix+item_prefix);
        function allPossibleCases(arr) {
            if (arr.length == 1) {
                return arr[0];
            }
            else {
                var result = [];
                var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
                for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                        result.push(arr[0][j] +'.'+ allCasesOfRest[i]);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

    };
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/prazj7qp/

Answer (score 0):

For those who understood my problem, this is my solution :

```
  function generate_jquery_selector_from_fitlers(filters){
  var number_of_values = 1;
  $.each( filters, function( index, selectors ) {
    number_of_values = number_of_values*selectors.length;
    return number_of_values;
  });
  filters_length = $.map( filters, function( selectors, i ) {
    return selectors.length;
  });
  var string_selector= '';
  for(var i =0; i < number_of_values;i++){
    var current = i;
    $.each( filters, function( index, selectors ) {
      var ind = parseInt(current % filters_length[index]);
      var ligne = selectors[ ind ];
      current = parseInt(current / filters_length[index]);
      string_selector += '.' + ligne;
    });
    string_selector += ',';
  }
  return string_selector.substring(0, string_selector.length - 1);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/skncsvw0/